# Print Eloquent SQL

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to print or get my eloquent SQL.

**My eloquent**

```
$proyectos = Proyectos::where('tipo','1')
     ->orWhere(function ($query)  {
       $query->where('desde', '<=', $this->fechaDesde);
       $query->where('desde', '>=', $this->fechaHasta);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query)  {
         $query->where('hasta', '<=', $this->fechaDesde);
         $query->where('hasta', '>=', $this->fechaHasta);
    })
    ->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
```

I can **print this SQL** doing this.

```
$proyectos = Proyectos::where('tipo','1')
         ->orWhere(function ($query)  {
           $query->where('desde', '<=', $this->fechaDesde);
           $query->where('desde', '>=', $this->fechaHasta);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query)  {
             $query->where('hasta', '<=', $this->fechaDesde);
             $query->where('hasta', '>=', $this->fechaHasta);
        })
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')->toSql();
```

But in the result  get **?**

```
select * from `proyecto` where `tipo` = ? and (`desde` <= ? and `desde` >= ? or `hasta` <= ? or `hasta` >= ?) and `proyecto`.`deleted_at` is null order by `id` desc
```

I don't know if is posible to get easier way and without ?

Something like that ( I know it is not like that )

```
 $sql = $proyectos->toSql();
 dd($sql);
// the result should be... 
select * from `proyecto` where `tipo` = `1` and (`desde` <= `2017-01-01` and `desde` >= `2017-06-01` or `hasta` <= `2017-01-01` or `hasta` >= `2017-06-01`) and `proyecto`.`deleted_at` is null order by `id` desc
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to install Laravel Debugbar. It shows all the real queries which were executed during the last request.

Comment: Yes I have it, but in this case I use one function in the controller when I export  a doc file and debugbar is not working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = str_replace(array('?'), array('\'%s\''), $proyectos->toSql());
$query = vsprintf($query, $proyectos->getBindings());
dd($query);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.